# How to pass checkbox checked as a parameter in controller function using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a web program that generates a random password based on the parameters that the user chooses by checking/unchecking checkboxes. I am now unable to transfer the users choices to the controller as a parameter in one of the functions. I always get a false regardless of whether the user has checked the box or not, seeing as how I made use of optional parameters with the default value being false, just incase the user does not check all the boxes.

I have set the names of the checkboxes and i have used those names in the arguments of the function that I call. This however still gets me a false regardless of whether the user checked the boxes or not

This is the cshtml section of my code

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("PasswordGenerator", "Generator", FormMethod.Post))
        {
                <table class="TablePre">

                    <tr class="TableTop">

                        <th>Preferences</th>

                    </tr>

                    <tr >
                        <td class="Spacing">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="letters" name="letters" id="iletters"/>
                            <label for="letters">Letters</label>
                        </td >
                    </tr>

                    <tr >
                        <td class="Spacing">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="numbers" name="numbers" id="inumbers" />
                            <label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr >
                        <td class="Spacing">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="symbols" name="symbols" id="isymbols" />
                            <label for="symbols">Symbols</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="Spacing">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="words" name="words" id="iwords" />
                            <label for="words">Words</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="Spacing">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="creative" name="creative" id="icreative" />
                            <label for="creative">Add my creative touch</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr >
                        <td class="Spacing">
                            <label style="display: inline-block" for="pLength">Password Length:</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text"  name="PLChoice" id="pLength" />                    
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td style="text-align:right;" class="TableTop">

                        <button type="submit"> Generate <span class="fas fa-cog"> </span> </button>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                </table> @* End of Table for password Generation preferences *@

                <br />
                <br />
                <br />

                <table class="TablePre TableSpacing">

                    <tr class="TableTop">

                        <th>Output</th>

                    </tr>


        } @* End of form *@
```

and this is the c# part of the code

```
        public ActionResult PasswordGenerator(bool letters = false , bool numbers = false, bool symbols = false, bool words = false, bool creative = false, int PLChoice = 0)
        {

            return View("Index");

        }
```

last example : If the user clicks on the letters checkbox, the Boolean letters will remain false instead of changing to true.

I expect the choices of the user to be transferred to the controller but what is happening is im getting false regardless of whether they checked the checkbox or not.[This is what the web program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeTa4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `value="true"` for all checkbox like

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="numbers" id="inumbers" />
```

Update tr as below

```
<tr>
            <td class="Spacing">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="letters" id="iletters" />
                <label for="letters">Letters</label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="Spacing">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="numbers" id="inumbers" />
                <label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="Spacing">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="symbols" id="isymbols" />
                <label for="symbols">Symbols</label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="Spacing">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="words" id="iwords" />
                <label for="words">Words</label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="Spacing">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="creative" id="icreative" />
                <label for="creative">Add my creative touch</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```